# Shouldn't a loop spawned in a thread print repeatedly?

Tags: rust

Example code:

```rust
fn main() {
    use std::thread::spawn;
    spawn(|| { loop { println!("a") } });
    // `a` is never printed
}
```

```rust
fn main() {
    use std::thread::spawn;
    spawn(|| { loop { println!("a") } });
    loop { }
    // `a` is printed repeatedly
}
```

`a` prints to the standard output in the second case, but the same is not true in the first case. Why is that? Shouldn't `a` print repeatedly in the first case as well?

Comment: Note: you are ignoring the return value of `thread::spawn`, if you used it, you could query whether the thread has completed, or wait for its completion (which might take a while for an infinite loop).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Shouldn't `a` print repeatedly in the first case as well?

No. The documentation of [`thread:spawn`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/thread/fn.spawn.html) says (emphasis mine):

> The join handle will implicitly detach the child thread upon being dropped. In this case, the child thread may outlive the parent (**unless the parent thread is the main thread; the whole process is terminated when the main thread finishes.**) Additionally, the join handle provides a join method that can be used to join the child thread. If the child thread panics, join will return an Err containing the argument given to panic.

Your entire program exits because the main thread has exited. There was never even a chance for the child thread to start, much less print anything.

In the second example, you prevent the main thread from exiting by also causing that to spin forever.

> What happens when you `spawn` a loop?

That thread will spin in the loop, *as long as the program executes*.

---

Idiomatically, you don't need the extra curly braces in the `spawn`, and it's more standard to only import the `std::thread` and then call `thread::spawn`:

```rust
fn main() {
    use std::thread;
    thread::spawn(|| loop {
        println!("a")
    });
}
```

To have the main thread wait for the child, you need to keep the [`JoinHandle`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/thread/struct.JoinHandle.html) from `thread::spawn` and call [`join`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/thread/struct.JoinHandle.html#method.join) on it:

```rust
fn main() {
    use std::thread;
    let handle = thread::spawn(|| loop {
        println!("a")
    });
    
    handle.join().expect("The thread panicked");
}
```

Comment: I read the part in bold before posting this question but it wasn't that clear to me. It's clear to me now. Thx.