# Why does my program exit even though I spawn a task that should loop forever?

Tags: asynchronous, rust, task

When I call `do_update().await` in `main`, it prints out "Foo" but the loop appears to stop rather than blocking the program from returning. What's the cause of this?

```rust
async fn do_update() {
    task::spawn(async {
        let duration = Duration::from_millis(10);
        let mut stream = tokio::time::interval(duration);
        stream.tick().await;
        loop {
            println!("Foo");
            stream.tick().await;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: See also [Shouldn't a loop spawned in a thread print repeatedly?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41597833/155423). Concepts from multithreaded programs often apply in asynchronous programs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you need to store the task in a variable and call `.await` on it,

```
async fn do_update() {
    // here we store it.
    let task = task::spawn(async {
        let duration = Duration::from_millis(10);
        let mut stream = tokio::time::interval(duration);
        stream.tick().await;
        loop {
            println!("Foo");
            stream.tick().await;
        }
    });
    // and here we await it.
    task.await;
}
```

Otherwise you create the task, but you don't actually specify that the task needs to be resolved before the program terminates.